# Why my application get stretched on Xcode 6.1 and not 5.1.1?

Tags: xcode, xcode6, xcode5

I have an application on Xcode that loads a local website in it. When I run it via Xcode 5.1.1 it runs as expected but when I run it with Xcode 6.1 it looks like it is zooming the window (stretching) what should I change ? I compared majority of the settings and they were all the same.
The only difference is that, the simulator of the one that works is based on iOS 7.1 and the one that does not work as expected runs on iOS 8.1, but how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, the issue is with the simulator. Just change the simulator and try to test it on a real device. It is highly recommended to test the product on a real device to find the issues.

Comment: Daniel is correct, testing on a real device is encouraged anyway to find memory issues etc.